# Error al ejecutar JBoss 7.2.3

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jboss-eap, jboss-as-7

Por favor me pueden explicar a que se debe este error cuando ejecutar el JBoss 7.2.3.

```
    20:17:27,740 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.2.4.Final-redhat-00001 (Apache CXF 3.2.9.redhat-00002)
20:17:27,745 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "jdbc/HARECL")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.Oracle6"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "org.wildfly.data-source.jdbc/HARECL is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.Oracle6]",
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:/jboss/datasources/HARECL is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.Oracle6]"
    ]
}
20:17:27,747 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "jdbc/HARECL")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.Oracle6",
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.Oracle6"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "org.wildfly.data-source.jdbc/HARECL is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.Oracle6]",
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:/jboss/datasources/HARECL is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.Oracle6]",
        "org.wildfly.data-source.jdbc/HARECL is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.Oracle6]"
    ]
}
```

he configurado de esta forma el standalone.xml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La JNDI del proyecto se encuentra de la siguiente manera:

################ JNDI ################

#app.jdbc.jndi=jdbc/APP_HARECL

app.jdbc.jndi=java:jboss/datasources/HARECL

Comment: Que es la configuración del driver ?

Comment: Pareciera que no tienes instalado el driver en el servidor, revisa esta guía https://gulinfounam.wordpress.com/2018/07/17/instalar-drivers-de-oracle-y-mysql-en-jboss-eap-7-1/